# Obtener data-id de elementos HTML en Jquery

Tags: jquery, api

el código anda perfecto, el único problema es que cuando quiero pasar por parámetros los ids a otra función(mostrar un modal), me los tira undefined.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    const key = '98430029';
    
    $('#form').on('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        const input = $('#search').val();

        if(input === ''){
            $('#error').html('No se encontraron resultados'); 
        } else {
            $('#error').html(''); 

            getMovies(input)
        }
    })

    function getMovies(movie){

        axios.get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${key}&s=${movie}`)
            .then(response => {
                const movies = response.data.Search;
                let template = '';

                $.each(movies, (i, info) => {
                    
                    template += `
                        <div class="card col-12 col-md-4">
                            <img data-id="${info.imdbID}" class="card-img-top" src="${info.Poster === 'N/A' ? '': info.Poster}">
                            <div class="card-body text-center">
                                <h5 class="card-title">${info.Title}</h5>
                                <a id="detail" class="btn btn-success w-100" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-details">
                                    Ver más
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>                              
                    `;
                    
                })
               
                $('#content').html(template);
                
                  const listaId = $("img").map(function(){
                    return $(this).attr("data-id");
                  }).get();

                $('#detail').on('click', showDetails(listaId))
               
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
    function showDetails(id) {
        
        axios.get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${key}&i=${id}`)
        .then(response => {
            const info = response.data;
            console.log(info)
            let template = `
                <div class="modal fade" id="modal-details" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-details" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal-details">${info.Title}</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <p>Description: ${info.Plot}</p>
                                <p><strong>Actors: ${info.Actors}</strong></p>
                                <p><i>Genre: ${info.Genre}</i></p>
                                <p><small>Year: ${info.Year}</small></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             `;
            $("body").append(template);
        })
    }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Buscador de Peliculas</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="display-4 text-center py-4">Encuentra tu película</h1>
        <form class="text-center" id="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" 
                       class="form-control " 
                       id="search" aria-describedby="textSearch" 
                       placeholder="Nombre de tu película"
                >
            </div>
            <button type="submit" 
                    class="btn btn-success w-100" 
                    id="btn-search">
                    Buscar
            </button>
        </form>
        <div class="text-danger text-left py-2" id="error"></div>  
    </div>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div id="content" class="row"></div>   
    </div>
    


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Este el ui de app
[image: Este es el ui de la app]

Comment: Hola Juan, bienvenido al sitio, Si desea obtener todos los `ids`, no debería hacer otra selección , solo crea un array antes del `$.each` y en cada iteración del `each`, has un `push` del id.

Comment: Hola Joel, gracias por la rapidez, lo probaré.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente como lo estas haciendo siempre te mostrará el primero, debes recorrer cada elemento y obtener su atribuo `data-id` y almacenarlo en una variable:

```js
var lista = $("img").map(function(){
              return $(this).attr("data-id");
            }).get();

console.log(lista);
```

```css
.item{
  border:1px solid red;
  display:inline-block;
  height:60px;
  width:60px;
}

.item:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img data-id="1" class="item" src="..." alt="imagen1">
<img data-id="2" class="item" src="..." alt="imagen2">
<img data-id="3" class="item" src="..." alt="imagen3">
<img data-id="4" class="item" src="..." alt="imagen4">
```

**UPDATE**

Para tu código sugiero que le coloques una clase y no lo invoques por el **id** ya que muchos botones tendrán el mismo **id** y te va a dar problemas, según mi sugerencia quedaría así:

```
$.each(movies, (i, info) => {

                    template += `
                        <div class="card col-12 col-md-4">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="${info.Poster === 'N/A' ? '': info.Poster}">
                            <div class="card-body text-center">
                                <h5 class="card-title">${info.Title}</h5>
                                <a id="detail" class="detail btn btn-success w-100" data-target="#modal-details" data-id="${info.imdbID}">
                                    Ver más
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>                              
                    `;

                })
```

Como le agregué la clase `detail`, la idea de todo esto es hacer un evento click donde puedas obtener dicho **id** y el **atributo data-id** lo movi para el dicho botón, ahora hagamos el evento click:

```
$(".detail").click(function(){

  let id = $(this).attr("data-id");
  showDetails(id);

});
```

Si te fijas al darle click obtengo el id de uno de sus atributos llamado `data-id` y luego se lo paso a la función `showDetails()`

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Hola David, perfecto, pero si quiero pasar por parámetro esos id para mostrar un modal, me tira undefined, ya está editado.

Comment: y cuando pasas el id por parametros? me imagino que le das click a la imagen, un div o un botón para capturar el id y luego abrir la modal cierto?

Comment: Fíjate ahí, está en el código no esta completamente editado, es por eso que no lo veías, fue mi error. Efectivamente cuando doy click en "Ver más", el modal anda todo perfecto, pero me tira que no encontró el id, entonces esa información que ves en el modal, esta undefined.

Comment: Ok en el botón ver más colocale una clase la puedes llamar detail, es porque con el id te va a dar error, ya edito mi respuesta para que te fijes como queda el botón y el evento click para llamar a la modal

Comment: Veo que el botón ver más llama a la modal, tienes el evento cuando la modal se abre? es decir tienes algún evento que captura cuando la ventana modal se abre?

Comment: Ahí lo edite, el click era al botón Ver más con el id="detail". El tema es en "listaId", es un array, entonces cuando pasa a showDetails, pasa como array, por eso me tira error.

Comment: Listo modifique mi respuesta, revisala y me cuentas

Comment: No me muestra el modal, pero los datos en console.log estan perfectos, un lujo David.